# Joomla onContentBeforeSave - resize image

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to create a plugin for Joomla 3 which automatically resizes an image when a logged in user is uploading it in the media manager.

What I tried so far:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class PlgSystemEasyImageResizer extends JPlugin
{
    protected $allowedMimeTypes = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


    public function onContentBeforeSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
        if ($context == 'com_media.file') {
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('MY MESSAGE');

            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(strval($article));
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(var_dump($article->tmp_name));
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(var_dump($article->path));
            JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(var_dump($article->type));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But after uploading I only recieve the following messages:

```
MY MESSAGE
Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject
Fertig hochgeladen: /AAAAAAAAA.jpg
```

How can I get the image from this object and resize it? (I want to use the native php functions).

And how can I return the resized image which should be saved?

Comment: Seems like a good question to post at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange (where Joomla devs hang out).

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks, I did not know this place existed!

Comment: Too few Joomla users do -- this is why I keep an eye on things here as well as JSE.  Sadly, many joomla tagged questions go unresolved on Stack Overflow.  This might get your creative juices flowing: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=818457

Comment: You might try https://www.powr.io/tutorials/how-to-add-image-resizer-extension-to-your-joomla-site or maybe look under the hood.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for sharing those links. Unfortunatel they were not really helpfull :( The useres did not share their achievements.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't delivering a solution.  You'll need to delve deeper.  When you post on JSE, please clarify the dimensions that you intend to apply and show your native php resizing code written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:
Hook into the afterSave event and edit the image after it was saved.

```
    public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
        if ($context == 'com_media.file') {
            // JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage('Filepath: ' . $article->filepath);
            if ($article->type == 'image/jpeg' or $article->type == 'image/png') {
                $orig_image = new JImage($article->filepath);
                // 750 will be set accordind to image ratio depending on 1000
                $resized_image = $orig_image->resize(1000, 750, true, JImage::SCALE_INSIDE);
                $resized_image->toFile($article->filepath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at one of the two following solutions:

1. 'Easy Image Resizer' a plugin that does what you wish to do https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/eir-easy-image-resizer/
2. 'Quantum Manager' a new component that replaces and extend the standard mediamanager you know. Loads of features from resize to modifying https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/quantum-manager/

Comment: Stack Overflow does not permit the recommendation 3rd party resources.  This is not a restriction on JSE.